# Unable to use DatabaseMigrations in Laravel Dusk SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-dusk

Full error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `sessions` where `id` = NAaXsoKQ6Tw9qmLO4VOC2MFFjFaXAN6Cut6Df9wf limit 1)
```

I'm trying to do browser testing using laravel Dusk,

Here's the dusk ENV file

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=sqlite_dusk
```

in the database.php

```
'connections' => [

    'sqlite_dusk' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => database_path('dusk.sqlite'),
    ],
```

I've also have dusk.sqlite in root of my database folder

Answer (score 1):

Try downgrading the chrome binaries.

Run:

```
php artisan dusk:chrome-driver 86
```

This issue is with Chrome 87.x binaries installed.

You must have used: php artisan dusk:chrome-driver --all